# Setting up QuickFIX/J with HTTP Proxy in PCF

Tags: http-proxy, fix-protocol, quickfixj

We are trying to setup QuickFIX/J using HTTP Proxy in PCF cloud which will interact with HTTP PROXY to send and receive FIX messages from outside third party.

We are not able to find any good comprehensive documentation for setting up HTTP PROXY with QuickFIX/J.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the proxy options in the official documentation?

[QFJ configuration](https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.1.0/usage/configuration.html) (search for "proxy")

Which version of QFJ are you using? There was a proxy-related bug fixed in the latest version 2.2.0. See [Preferred proxy authentication methods removed](https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/pull/296)

Comment: Thanks for your response, i have checked the QFJ documentation it only talks about the configuration properties. More over i am looking for some more detailed information how to set it up (i am just new to all this). In this other link you have shared can you share some sample configs we need to put in proxy and FIX engine.

Comment: can you please provide help here.

Comment: I cannot help you with the config of the proxy. The QFJ config options can be found under the link I provided. I think you need to setup your stuff and come here for help with error messages since no-one would be able to guide you through the complete configuration of a proxy.